# System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint constructor causes the Exception to be thrown

Tags: vb.net, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a piece of code that caused an Exception. **The exception was only thrown once and the scenario cannot be replicated**. But I still want to make sense of this error.
Here is the code:

```
1 Dim myHost As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(New ClientService())
2 myBinding = New NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
3 Dim clientAddress As String = "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:3500/Client"
4 myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IClientService), myBinding, clientAddress)
```

The IP address is for example only. In production it was a valid IP address of the client machine.
The Exception is thrown in line #4. Here is the stack:

```
1   System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
2   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
3   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
4   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(Type implementedContract, Binding binding, String address, Uri listenUri)
5   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(Type implementedContract, Binding binding, String address)
```

Questions:

1. Why is  overloaded **AddServiceEndpoint(Type implementedContract, Binding binding, String address, Uri listenUri)** called if I only called **AddServiceEndpoint(Type implementedContract, Binding binding, String address)**?
2. What can be a possible cause of that Exception?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The actual code for clientAddress string is:

```
clientAddress = String.Format(My.Resources.UrlTemplate,ip.AddressList(0).ToString(), CInt(Int((1024 - 808 + 1) * Rnd() + 808)))
```

where

```
Dim ip As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
```

I simplified the first code example for the clarity sake. Resources.resx is the Embeded resource in the production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are many overloads of `AddServiceEndpoint`, and it's common practice to have one overload which does most of the work, and others which (usually) take less parameters and just call the more complete overload - and this is the case, as you can see in the stack trace. `AddServiceEndpoint(Type, Binding, String)` calls internally `AddServiceEndpoint(Type, Binding, String, Uri)`.
2. You say that it doesn't reproduce anymore, so without the actual value it's hard to guess what could have gone wrong. Based on the exception, the value of `clientAddress` was definitely at fault, but without knowing the value which caused that problem we can only guess. You can get the same exception, for example, if you use `"net.tcp://"` as the value of that variable.

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira. I just thought msdn documentation would include that info. As to the second point - see my recent edits to the post. Thanks again.